# Power BI Table Automatically Removing Duplicate Rows Error

Tags: duplicates, powerbi

The table visualization is currently removing rows with all duplicate values. I know that it can see all of the rows because in a different visualization it counts them.

I don't see a setting to turn this remove duplicates feature off. In the values section I have "Don't summarize" checked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post what you are seeing and what you expect to see?

Comment: Thanks Alexis, I did try to post a picture but apparently I'm too new to complete that. Basically I'm seeing this:  

PM, 3/29/2018, Open
PC, 3/29/2018, Open
PC, 3/28/2018, Open

But I expect to see this
PM, 3/29/2018, Open
PC, 3/29/2018, Open
PC, 3/29/2018, Open
PC, 3/28/2018, Open

Comment: @StevenB Do you have multiple columns on the table ? if you have multiple columns and you doing a summary (Addition, count etc.,) on one of those columns, then it will by default give you the unique values on the first column.